# DataTables fnClearTable Changing Column Widths

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable, datatables

Ok. I have a problem with DataTables where I am not able to get the DataTable to re-populate with the same column widths it used to have even if it's re-populating with the same data.

I'm not sure if it's the act of calling fnClearTable that is changing things or if it is re-populating the table, but something is changing the column widths and I don't know how to fix it!

Look at this in JsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/h47N2/

I've even tried calling fnAdjustColumnSizing (shown below), but that doesn't fix it either

```
$('#tableID').dataTable().fnAdjustColumnSizing();
```

To run the JsFiddle example, just click "Run" on the top, then click "draw," "clear," then "redraw" in that order. Play around with it a bit and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Basically, I'm populating a DataTable in jQuery, then calling fnClearTable, then populating it again with the same data. The first time it populates, it's great! Perfect even. The second time, however, it changes all of the widths of the columns and I cannot figure out how to get it back to the way it was the first time the table was drawn.

Please help as I have seen this when using DataTables multiple times on multiple projects and it's really starting to get on my nerves!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the initialisation option [**`bAutoWidth`**](http://www.datatables.net/ref) :

> Enable or disable automatic column width calculation. This can be
>   disabled as an optimisation (it takes some time to calculate the
>   widths) if the tables widths are passed in using aoColumns.

For some not-so-clear reason is `bAutoWidth`'s default value true. Thats why you have seen this behaviour over and over :) Simply set this option to false - forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/aYhm4/**

```js
$('#t').dataTable({
   ...
   bAutoWidth : false
   ...
});
```

Comment: I noticed that it matters where you place this. I had this property in the middle, but when I moved it to the end, it fixed the problem! THANK YOU!